# more than one version of gcc installed

Tags: 14.04, gcc

When I enter `clang++ -v` it outputs

> > Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)
> >     [...]
> >     Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
> >     Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.2
> >     Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
> >     Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.1
> >     Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8

It seems that I have more than one GCC version installed. However when I enter `g++ --version` it says

> > g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

So my questions are:

**1) Why do I have more than one GCC installed?**

More importantly:

**2) Why does it not select the most recent version?**

**3) Why does it chose a different GCC for g++ than for clang?**

**4) What consequences does this have? Could it be that e.g. Qt choses an older version of GCC? See my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857253/return-type-deduction-and-function-declarations).**